# I keep getting "error package com.mongodb does not exist" when trying to compile MongoDB Utilites class

Tags: java, mongodb, classpath

I am running a webapp using a connection to MongoDB where products reviews are stored. The current version of the webapp works correctly. (i.e. it writes and stores new reviews in the MongoDB collection).

Nonetheless, when I make changes and try to compile a new version of the MongoDB Utilities class I keep getting:

```
error package com.mongodb.XXX does not exist
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
                  ^
```

I do have the following .jar files in the \lib directory:

```
mongodb-driver-3.6.3
mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3
mongodb-java-driver-3.6.3
bson-3.6.3
```

and I mentioned them in the CLASSPATH variable:

```
set CLASSPATH=.;C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.34\lib\servlet-api.jar;C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.34\lib\jsp-api.jar;C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.34\lib\el-api.jar;C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.34\lib\commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar; C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.34\lib\mongo-java-driver-3.6.3.jar; C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.34\lib\bson-3.6.3;C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.34\lib\mongodb-driver-3.6.3; C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.34\lib\mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3;  C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.34\lib\mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar;
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I get java to compile my new MongoDB Utilities class?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce the same behaviour, but I only reference `mongodb-java-driver-3.6.3` in my build scripts.

Since the `mongodb-java-driver` is an uber JAR that contains `mongodb-driver`, `mongodb-driver-core`, and `bson`, you could try removing these latter three from your classpath and build scripts and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: You are right, when I solved the issue (doing what I posted as an answer) I only need to use the java-driver and not the other 3. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my issue so I post this answer in case someone is stuck in the same problem.

Thanks to what user "nos" posts in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579846/java-wont-compile-with-requestdispatcher-classpath-set-correctly?rq=1) I used the -verbose option when compiling e.g.:

`javac -verbose className.java`

In the errors log I noticed that the Java compiler was searching for the MongoDB classes in a different `\lib` folder than the one I used in my CLASSPATH definition. So I added a copy of the `mongodb-java-driver` there and the compilation worked.

As craigcaulfield correctly mentions above there is no need to add the other drivers ( `mongodb-driver`, `mongodb-driver-core`, and `bson`).